# Pagination not working on exp:search:search_results in expression engine

Tags: expressionengine

Pagination link not working on  expression engine exp:search results.Page does not display the new result when pagination link is clicked.

```
 {exp:search:total_results}</b>Result(s) for <b>{exp:search:keywords} 
      {exp:search:search_results entry_id={entry_id}  
        switch="#000000|#003300"  status="Open" 
        dynamic="off"  orderby="date" sort="desc"} 

    {exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo" paginate="bottom"    limit="2"}

        <?php $articlePath = "article";?>
        {related_entries id="article_feature"}

          {if title == "Bay Blog"}<?php $articlePath = "blog";?>  
        {/related_entries} 

          <b><a href="{title_permalink="/blog/"}">{title}</a></b> from <em>{related_entries id="article_feature"}{title} {/related_entries}</em><br/>
          {if:else}

          <b><a href="{title_permalink="/article/"}">{title}</a></b> from <em>{related_entries id="article_feature"}{title} {/related_entries}</em><br/>
          {/if}     

          {exp:trunchtml chars="250" inline="..."}
                  {article_body}
           {/exp:trunchtml}
           {related_entries id="article_issue"}
            <a href="/issue/{entry_id}"> [ {title}] </a> {/related_entries}
            <br><br>
          {if no_results}
            Sorry!, Search result found!
        {/if} 
   {/exp:search:search_results}
{paginate}
        <div class='paginate'>
            <span class='pagecount'>{page_count}</span>&nbsp;
        </div>
{paginate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning [search results](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/search/results.html#auto-path), use the `auto_path` variable when building your URLs:

```
<a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a>
```

Unlike other path variables, this variable *does not require* the Template Group and Template Name to be specified.

Instead, the path will automatically be determined by the [Search Results URL setting](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#search-results-url) for the channel in Channel Management.

**Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Preferences:**

[image: General Channel Preferences]

---

If you're using **ExpressionEngine's Pages Module** or **Structure** to create static pages, the following use case may be of help to you as well:

```
{if page_url == ""}
    // If the Search Result is a Dynamic Page
    <a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a>
{/if}

{if page_url != ""}
    // If the Search Result is a Static Page
    <a href="{page_url}">{title}</a>
{/if}
```

You can also test to see what channel the search result is being fetched from and act on it conditionally:

```
{if channel_name == "about"}
    <a href="{page_url}">{title}</a>
{if:else}
    <a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: Got it work by clearing the cache setting and by synchronizing the templates on the expression engine side.